# Coexistence of different solutions in a nonlinear matrix differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, matrix-equations, perturbation-theory

I've faced a system of first-order nonlinear matrix differential equation, and I have tried to use perturbation method to approach the solutions.

The differential equation has the form:

\begin{align}
\frac{d\mathbf{F}}{d\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{x}$ is the variable vector and $\epsilon$ is a parameter. 
I focus on the steady state, which yields the solution of $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)=0$. This equation actually has several solutions.

Assume that the equation has a perturbation solution 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{a}\epsilon +\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\end{align}
for the parameter $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. 
Meanwhile, the equation has a perturbation solution 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}_0-\mathbf{b}_1\epsilon^{-1} +\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{-2})
\end{align}
for the parameter $\epsilon\rightarrow \infty$.

Now I already know (from numerical simulations) that the above two kinds of solutions i.e., $x_i\rightarrow 0$ for $i\in I$ and $x_j\rightarrow b_0$ for $j\in J$, coexists for the parameter $\epsilon$ of a specific value interval. In physics, this may mean phases coexistence.
My question is how to identify the solution sets $I$ and $J$?

Thanks in advance for any remark and suggested literature.

Comment: $I$ and $J$ are sets of what?  Values of $\epsilon$?

Comment: The dimension of vector $\mathbf{x}$ is $k$. Define $K=\{1,2,...,k\}$, the set $I\in K$ and $J\in K$ and $I \cap J = \emptyset$.

Comment: Presumably you mean $I \subseteq K$ and $J \subseteq K$.  But in the perturbation solutions the whole vector goes to the appropriate limit.  There is generally no reason to have some coordinates doing one and other coordinates doing the other, unless the equations decouple.